# I want a second QSettings file in my App for some settings that will be shared with other Apps

Tags: c++, linux, qt

I have a regular `QSettings` object (and file) for my App. Some time ago I added a second `QSettings` called `gsettings` for some "global" settings that are shared between several Apps. That worked fine. That was added in my `main.cpp` file with this statement:

```
QApplication app(argc, argv);
QSettings gsettings("GNN", "CMP_G_ALL");
```

But now I want access to this settings file from elsewhere in my code, so I moved the line to my `mainwindow.cpp` (also tried `mainwindow.h`.) But I get an error "expected parameter declarator" or it wants empty `()`.

How do I make a secondary settings file that I can use throughout my code?

Or how can I make the one in `main.cpp` accessible elsewhere in my code?

If I just declare:

```
QSettings gsettings();
```

in my `mainwindow.h` file, which I can without an error, then how do I give it the location subdirectory and name?

This doesn't seem like it should be difficult, but nothing I have read seems to address it.

Comment: Please show your code -- preferably in the form of a [mcve].  Note that `QSettings gsettings();` probably doesn't do what you think: it declares a function `gsettings` that takes no parameters and returns a `QSettings`.

Comment: @G.M. Well, I actually have now figured out something that works, although it seems a little awkward. ... Later: Now I am confused, because I just tried the same line `QSettings xsettings("GNN", "CMP_G_ALL");` in my `mainwindow.cpp` and it compiles without error. So I have no idea why it didn't before - and thus why I posted the question. (Should the whole question be deleted?)